# How to cache directory contents in Azure Pipelines, and invalidate on a condition like package.json file changing?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

For example, cache the contents of `node_modules` unless `package.json` changes.

AppVeyor supports this, where somehow it knows that `package.json` changed and will invalidate its cached `node_modules` folder that it copies into the VM build work area.

Comment: "We are actively looking into a build caching solution for Azure Pipelines, we have done some initial design work and hope to start work on it in the new year." https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9190#issuecomment-450232972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be now achieved by using the `Cache` task. More info can be found [on MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/caching/?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm) (it also has many examples for well-known apps) but in general it goes like this:

[image: step screenshot]

or in YAML

```
steps:
- task: Cache@2
  displayName: 'Cache npm'
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package.json'
    path: '$(npm_config_cache)'
```

The idea is that you specify a cache key, which could be a string or a file content (exactly what you're asking for) and the path to cache. You don't need a separate restore task, this one works in both directions.

Note, that for this example you should also define the `npm_config_cache` environment variable.